# Grub loads but only show the purple screen

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

When my laptop is booting I can't see the menu, but grub is there, if I press enter it boots my first option, it's only showing the purple screen.

I'm pretty sure it's some video setting, but I don't know what to change.

My Configuration:
UBUNTU 12.04 LTS
LAPTOP ASUS N56VZ
GEFORCE GT 550M