# GRUB boots Ubuntu to dark purple screen, forced to override with Advanced options works but how do I set that as the default?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 17.10

## The Details

I am dual booting Ubuntu 17.10 on a Razer Blade 14" that also has Windows 8.1 installed.

On boot, it shows the dark purple-ish GRUB screen, stating "GNU GRUB Version 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7" at the top center and the following options on the upper left:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for Ubuntu
- Windows Boot Mangaer (on /dev/sda2)
- System setup

In the past (before I replaced my SSD with a new one and reinstalled both OS') I could select the first option in the list below "Ubuntu", and it would load Ubuntu accordingly.

## The Problem

But now, when I do that it switches to a blank, dark purple-ish screen indefinitely.

So, if I reboot and select "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and select "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.13.0-16-generic" then it will load accordingly. Here's the list of options:

- Ubuntu, with Linux 4.13.0-16-lowlatency
- Ubuntu, with Linux 4.13.0-16-lowlatency (recovery mode)
- Ubuntu, with Linux 4.13.0-16-generic
- Ubuntu, with Linux 4.13.0-16-generic (recovery mode)
- Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-37-generic
- Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-37-generic (recovery mode)

## My Question

How do I ensure Ubuntu loads normally, and automatically instead of being forced to take the steps above.

## What I've Tried

I have read the following articles and tried their proposed solutions without resolution:

- [Purple Screen, first time using Ubuntu | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185113/purple-screen-first-time-using-ubuntu)
- [Ubuntu blank purple screen on startup | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744589/ubuntu-blank-purple-screen-on-startup)
- [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it? | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/142683/724320)
- This caused my screen to go black instead of purple: [Ubuntu boot freeze / lockup with a blank purple or black screen | turriebuntu.wordpress.com](https://turriebuntu.wordpress.com/general-ubuntu-pages/ubuntu-boot-freeze-lockup-it-stops-with-a-blank-purple-or-black-screen/)
- I tried this and Boot Repair installs but when I attempt to open the app I just get a loading symbol and then nothing. [Boot-Repair | Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
- This didn't have an answer but it appears to be a similar question: [Grub loads but only show the purple screen | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181423/grub-loads-but-only-show-the-purple-screen)
- [Booting Ubuntu: Temporarily stuck on a purple screen | bleepingcomputer.com](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/598260/booting-ubuntu-temporarily-stuck-on-a-purple-screen/)

Comment: I have used 16.04 but I have not tried to replicate this issue on that version. I'm not clear as to how that's relevant, would you mind clarifying?

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. That might be solution for others but I can't do that in my case. Thanks for your time anyway.